# whats wrong with my Zipdll code?

Tags: nsis

```
#Var directoryexe# ;Declare the variable

###Section directory###
    StrCpy $DIRECTORYEXE "$EXEDIR"
###SectionEnd###

**Section "ZIP" locatezip**

ClearErrors

    ${Locate} "$DIRECTORYEXE" "/L=F /M=something.zip /S=1K" "ExtractZip"

    ; '.zip' file next to .exe with size 1 Kb or more

    IfErrors 0 noerror

    MessageBox MB_OK "ERRROR" IDOK +3

noerror:

MessageBox MB_OK "$$R0=$R0" 

**SectionEnd**
```

**Function ExtractZip**

```
    strcpy "$R0" "$R9"

    ZipDLL::extractall "$R0" "$PROGRAMFILES\Example"

    Pop $0

    MessageBox MB_OK "$$0=$0"

    StrCpy $0 StopLocate

    Push $0
```

**FunctionEnd**

And if zip is in the exedir, extract it but when its not there not write error message, whats the problem ? :S

Comment: How is this different from the question you already asked? You cannot just assume that IfErrors works, you have to read the documentation for the feature you are using. In this case checking the error from ZipDll::extractall should be enough...

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case you can probably use the error message you would get from ZipDLL::extractall when it cannot find the .zip.

`${Locate}` cannot know if not finding a file is a error or not. You have to keep track of this yourself. If your callback-function (ExtractZip) is never called then the file was not found...